# Pointwise limit of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it possible to construct a sequence of complex polynomial $  f_{n}(z)$ such than $  f_{n}(0) = 2$ for each n and pointwise limit of that is 1 at all non zero complex number?
I want to know that can whether  convergence is uniform on closed unit disk or not.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question: How could that be uniform on the closed unit disc? It would imply that the function that is $2$ at $0$ and $1$ everywhere else in the closed unit disc is continuous! (So forget about complex polynomials and holomorphic functions and other fancy things, there are no continuous functions that do this.)

Comment: Yes that is the question. First one is still open

Comment: OK, I'm guessing you recently covered Runge's theorem?

Comment: Yes. I read and i hope there is such function but dont know how to proceed plz help

Comment: Well then, you should have included Runge in your question, providing background, context, thoughts etc. Why don't you do that now?

Comment: I thought  it may me prove without that

Comment: Why would this question appear right after you covered Runge do you think?